# Retrieve posts I liked on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making some fb open graph query of the form `me/posts` and I get the right result.

However I also get stuff like,

{"story" "MY_NAME likes a status", "id" "MY-FACEBOOK-ID_OTHER-MISTERIOUS-ID"}

Since I am human I guessed that "OTHER-MISTERIOUS-ID" should be the ID of the status I liked, so I try to fetch such status, always on open-graph with a query like
`/OTHER-MISTERIOUS-ID`, but this query return empty.

Someone else faced the same problem ?
What they come out with ?

Comment: What is the full query that you use with OTHER-MISTERIOUS-ID??

Comment: I just made a request like `facebook.graph.com/OTHER-MISTERIOUS-ID` ...

Answer (score 0):

The post id cannot be changed. After retrieving the posts, you have to retrieve the likes for each post like this:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/likes?limit=10000&format=json&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

You will get response like this:

```
 {
"data": [
 {
  "id": "FACEBOOK_ID OF THE USER WHO LIKED THE POST",
  "name": "NAME OF THE USER"
}
],
"paging": {
"cursors": {
  "after": "******",
  "before": "***"
 }
 }
}
```

so you will get all users who liked a particular post, and you can easily compare the ids to find the posts that you liked.

Comment: Thanks, but I have the opposite problem, I want to identify the post itself, I am the user who likes the post...
Just query `graph.facebook.com/MY-FACEBOOK-ID_OTHER-MISTERIOUS-ID` doesn't work...

Comment: @Siscia are you passing the access token along with your requset?? Like this: https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN ??

Comment: take a look here: http://ilmiodiario.herokuapp.com/fb/show-new-trial/5273c3e6e4b0f173ae6375ae 
I want to complete the empty boxes, the json under the box is the data I get from facebook...
Take a look at the very first box, an empty one...From the json you can see that I commented a post of one of my friend in a group... How can I retrieve the post I commented to ?

Comment: You want something like this: http://www.4692.me/user/demo ?? The last box is for facebook